# Cross-platform advice Android / iOS / Windows

Tags: android, ios, windows, cross-platform

I'm maintaining a plethora of apps for one of my clients all of which have native projects for each of the three main platforms. The apps are relatively simple in functionality. My client wants to always take advantage of the latest features in each platform for marketing opportunities. They also want to appear to be a native app (responsive, not laggy). I haven't followed cross-platform development very much lately, so that's why I'm reaching out to SO.

My initial idea is to write a C++ library that has all the functionality shared by the three platforms. Then, for each platform, I'll write some network, file access, and UI-code that connects the abstract library code to the concrete platform.

Of course, this is exactly what cross-platform systems aim to do. Would it be a waste of my time to write the above myself when this has already been done by platforms like PhoneGap? My concern is that I would be dependent on a third-party. If I write the code myself, I have full control, and I will always have access to the latest features.

Hope to get some pro's and con's.

Thanks!

Comment: PhoneGap ( or Cordova) is not using any native controls, it's all webview with HTML and javascript. But you might want to have al look at ReactNactive. This cool project but only iOS and Android only at the moment. Your idea about using C++ for all platforms is also a great option.

Answer (score 2):

Yet a third option (after Facebook's React Native and Microsoft's Xamarin) is Google's new [Flutter](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14432857) and as the other answers suggests "then writing the Windows app purely natively". BTW, React Native [does have Windows support](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/04/13/react-native-on-the-universal-windows-platform/) the lack of which in Flutter could be a plus or a minus depending on how you look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using React Native for iOS and Android, then writing the Windows app purely natively?

There are tons of articles out there about pros and cons for React Native.

PhoneGap is just a web, written in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. React Native actually renders native components for iOS/Android.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Xamarin. It supports multiple platforms and uses c#. The new features from the native languages all work great.